# Checklist after submitting my app to App Store for reviewing

Tags: iphone, app-store, release

After submitting my app to App Store for reviewing, is there anything that I need to be ready before final approval? And also, would the app be immediately available for downloading once it's approved, can I "reserve" a couple days in between to cleanup/reset the backend database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Sign in to ITunes Connect

2) Go to Manage Your Application Section.

3) Click on your app.

4) On the top right you will see a section For Price and Release.

There you can set the release date for your app to the app store after review..

There is no need to be ready for anything else before final approval..
Good luck with your app :D

Answer (score 1):

No, that's it - once it is submitted it is out on its own.

You can set to be immediately available or you can specify the date and release it yourself.